# Angular factory returning a promise

Tags: angularjs

When my app starts I load some settings from a server. Most of my controllers need this before anything useful can be done. I want to simplify the controller's code as much as possible. My attempt, which doesn't work, is something like this:

```
app.factory('settings', ['$rootScope', '$http', '$q', function($rootScope, $http, $q) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    $http.get('/api/public/settings/get').success(function(data) {
        $rootScope.settings = data;
        deferred.resolve();
    });

    return deferred.promise;
}]);

app.controller('SomeCtrl', ['$rootScope', 'settings', function($rootScope, settings) {
    // Here I want settings to be available
}]);
```

I would like to avoid having a lot of settings.then(function() ...) everywhere.

Any ideas on how to solve this in a nice way?

Answer (score 19):

$http itself return promise you don't need to bind it inside the $q this is not a good practice and considered as Anti Pattern.

Use:-

```
    app.factory('settings', ['$rootScope', '$http', '$q', function($rootScope, $http) {
        return $http.get('/api/public/settings/get')
    }]);

    app.controller('SomeCtrl', ['settings',$scope, function(settings,$scope) {
        settings.then(function(result){
                $scope.settings=result.data;
          });
    }]);
```

Your way can be done as :-

```
app.factory('settings', ['$rootScope', '$http', '$q', function($rootScope, $http, $q) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    $http.get('/api/public/settings/get').success(function(data) {
        deferred.resolve(data);
    });

    return deferred.promise;
}]);

app.controller('SomeCtrl', ['$scope', 'settings', function($scope, settings) {
    settings.then(function(data){
          $scope.settings=data;
       })
}]);
```

Don't overload $rootScope if you wanted it you need to use $watch for the changes in $rootScope(Not recommended).

Comment: As I wrote I want to avoid the "settings.then"-part. Ideally I want the controller SomeCtrl to wait until settings has been loaded. Is that possible?

Comment: you need to solve it by only $watch in that case on $rootScope.settings but that is not good practice (permormance issue) dirty checking and new digest cycle will slow the perfomance.

Answer (score 14):

Somewhere you would need to "wait".

The only built-in way in Angular to completely absolve the controller from having to wait on its own for async data to be loaded is to instantiate a controller with `$routeProvider`'s route's `resolve` property (or the alternative `$stateProvider` of `ui.router`). This will run controller only when all the promises are resolved, and the resolved data would be injected.

So, **ng-route** alternative - [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/SFSMJQQJTaWuja1exacJ?p=preview):

```
$routeProvider.when("/", {
   controller: "SomeCtrl",
   templateUrl: "someTemplate.html",
   resolve: {
     settings: function(settingsSvc){
       return settingsSvc.load(); // I renamed the loading function for clarity
     }
   });
```

Then, in `SomeCtrl` you can add `settings` as an injectable dependency:

```
.controller("SomeCtrl", function($scope, settings){
   if (settings.foo) $scope.bar = "foo is on";
})
```

This will "wait" to load `someTemplate` in `<div ng-view></div>` until settings is resolved.

The `settingsSvc` should cache the promise so that it won't need to redo the HTTP request. Note, that as mentioned in another answer, there is no need for `$q.defer` when the API you are using (like `$http`) already returns a promise:

```
.factory("settingsSvc", function($http){
   var svc = {settings: {}};
   var promise = $http.get('/api/public/settings/get').success(function(data){
      svc.settings = data; // optionally set the settings data here
   });
   svc.load = function(){
      return promise;
   }
   return svc;
});
```

**Another approach**, if you don't like the `ngRoute` way, could be to have the `settings` service broadcast on `$rootScope` an event when settings were loaded, and controllers could react to it and do whatever. But that seems "heavier" than `.then`.

I guess **the third way** - [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/TgaVXkmy8fBc2bJOC6Pa?p=preview) - would be to have an app-level controller "enabling" the rest of the app only when all the dependencies have preloaded:

```
.controller("AppCtrl", function($q, settingsSvc, someOtherService){
   $scope.loaded = false;
   $q.all([settingsSvc.load, someOtherService.prefetch]).then(function(){
      $scope.loaded = true;
   });
});
```

And in the View, toggle `ng-if` with `loaded`:

```
<body ng-controller="AppCtrl">
  <div ng-if="!loaded">loading app...</div>

  <div ng-if="loaded">
    <div ng-controller="MainCtrl"></div>
    <div ng-controller="MenuCtrl"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Don't you need to return `svc` object in your factory function for *settingsSvc* service?

Answer (score 1):

Fo ui-router this is easily done with having an application root state with at least this minimum definition

```
$stateProvider
    .state('app', {
        abstract: true,
        template: '<div ui-view></div>'
        resolve:     {
            settings:  function($http){
                return $http.get('/api/public/settings/get')
                            .then(function(response) {return response.data});
            }
        }
    })
```

After this you can make all application states inherit from this root state and

1. All controllers will be executed only after settings are loaded
2. All controllers will gain access to **settings** resolved value as possible injectable.

As mentioned above *resolve* also works for the original **ng-route** but since it does not support nesting the approach is not as useful as for ui-router.

Answer (score 1):

You can manually bootstrap your application after settings are loaded.

```
var initInjector = angular.injector(["ng"]);
var $http = initInjector.get("$http");
var $rootScope = initInjector.get("$rootScope");

$http.get('/api/public/settings/get').success(function(data) {
    $rootScope.settings = data;
    angular.element(document).ready(function () {
        angular.bootstrap(document, ["app"]);
    });
});
```

In this case your whole application will run only after the settings are loaded.

See [Angular bootstrap documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap) for details