# Get Data from AngularJS HTTP post call in controller from factory

Tags: angularjs, factory

I'm posting data to a a Python API and the API response returns data that I want to use in a controller and eventually in one in HTML partial associated with that view. I'm able to successfully get the data as i'm logging the response.data from the call but when I call the method from my controler, I get an error stating cannot read property of "then" undefined.

```
 function getCustomerGraphData(payload, config) {

        var data = {
            user_selection: JSON.stringify(payload),
            index_info: JSON.stringify(config.index_info),
            column_config: JSON.stringify(config.Results)
        };

        console.log("data", data);

        $http({
            url: 'URL',
            method: "POST",
            data: $.param(data),
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
        }).then(function(response) {
            var customer = response.data;

            console.log("data", customer);

            return customer;
        });

    }
```

Service

```
 arisService.getCustomerGraphData()
        .then(function(data){
            $scope.overIndexData = data;
        })
```

Controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make sure your service is returning a `promise` so you can call it's `then` method, look at the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) for `$q` for more information on promises :

```
function getCustomerGraphData(payload, config, $q) {
   // initialize the defer object
   var deferred = $q.defer();

    var data = {
        user_selection: JSON.stringify(payload),
        index_info: JSON.stringify(config.index_info),
        column_config: JSON.stringify(config.Results)
    };

    console.log("data", data);

    $http({
        url: 'URL',
        method: "POST",
        data: $.param(data),
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
    }).then(function(response) {
        var customer = response.data;

        console.log("data", customer);

        // resolve the promise with your data
        deferred.resolve(customer);
    });

    // return the promise
    return deferred.promise;

}
```

Comment: awesome! and if I have multiple methods, I can declare the q.defer as a global variable and use it throughout the service?

Comment: if you are talking about dealing with multiple promises I'd recommend checking out $q.all, you can pass it an array of promises and it'll return a promise that resolves when all the promises you pass it resolve.

Answer (score 0):

Into you service you should return the promise create by the http call.

```
return $http(...)
```

Then you will have a promise with callback accessible into your controller like you want.

You may want to read something about promises if you are starting with angular, as they are frequently used.

[Angular factory returning a promise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28830003/angular-factory-returning-a-promise)

http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2014/Oct/24/AngularJs-and-Promises-with-the-http-Service

[Processing $http response in service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12505760/processing-http-response-in-service)

[Angular docs about $q service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)

Answer (score 0):

Inject `$q` as dependency inside factory and then promisify your method,

```
function getCustomerGraphData(payload, config) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        var data = {
            user_selection: JSON.stringify(payload),
            index_info: JSON.stringify(config.index_info),
            column_config: JSON.stringify(config.Results)
        };

        console.log("data", data);

        $http({
            url: 'URL',
            method: "POST",
            data: $.param(data),
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
        }).then(function(response) {
            var customer = response.data;
            deferred.resolve(customer);
            console.log("data", customer);

            return customer;
        });
      return deferred.promise;
    }
```