# Using data from one controller in another

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, mean

I am making a website based on MEAN. Now I am trying to pass data from one controller to the next, but I don't seem to get it done. When an option is selected I want to take this value to the next page

This is the page with the selectbox:

```
<div class="plumber-by-city col-sm-12 home-text-col" ng-controller="DataCtrl">
<div class="title-1">Search by cityname</div>
   <select ng-model="selectedItem" ng-change="change()" ng-options="item as item.city for item in items"></select><span class="fa fa-caret-down"></span>
</div>
```

On change I want to take the selectedItem passed through to the next page with DataCtrl2

This is my DataCtrl:

```
app.controller('DataCtrl', function($scope,$http,getData,$location,$routeParams){

   getData.getCity($scope);

   $scope.change = function() {
      $location.path('/plumber-in/' + $scope.selectedItem.city);
   };
});
```

And the service that retrieves data from DB:

```
app.factory('getData', function($http){
  return {
     getCity: function($scope){
       return $http.get("/getdata").then(function(response){
         $scope.items = response.data;
         $scope.selectedItem = response.data[0];
       });
     }
   };
});
```

Now I don't know what to put in the DataCtrl2 for the second page and how to use the data from the DataCtrl in this page

Comment: Is it possible to create a working JSFiddle? You could use a service to persist (with a setter / getter) the active city between the controllers or use stateparams to transfer this data to the next state.

Comment: @Larsmanson: make it simple, return promise from factory\service, and evaluate in controller. :)

Comment: @anoop: How could I do this. I am not familiar with that

Comment: @Larsmanson : See the answers of this [question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28830003/angular-factory-returning-a-promise) and in below answer `sachila` has done the same too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you need is a Setter and Getter Method in your service. Something like this

```
app.controller('DataCtrl', 
    function($scope,$http,getData,$location,$routeParams){

   getData.getCity().then(function(response) {
      $scope.items = response.data;
      $scope.selectedItem = response.data[0];
   });

   $scope.change = function() {
      // sets the data to the service
      getData.setItem($scope.selectedItem);

      $location.path('/plumber-in/' + $scope.selectedItem.city);         
   };

});

app.factory('getData', function($http){
  return {
     getCity: function(){
       return $http.get("/getdata");
     },

     setItem: function(item) {
         this.item = item;
     },

     getItem: function() {
         return this.item;
     }
   };
});

app.controller('DataCtrl2', 
    function($scope, $http, getData,$location,$routeParams){
        // get the data from the service
        getData.getItem();
});
```

Comment: Somehow it does not go to the other page but stays on the same page

Comment: @Larsmanson:  are you talking about the data or the page view? 
Also there was a an typo. Updated.

Comment: The pageview does not change

Comment: what error are you getting. Did you see the updated change.
Also, just add the part of code which I added to your existing working code,

Comment: I've updated your code to not pass scope around. Have a look.

Comment: Thanx, I will check it out

Answer (score 4):

don't use `$scope` inside the factory. just return the request-promise to the controller and do your logic in there.

```
app.factory('getData', function($http){
  return {
     getCity: function(){
       return $http.get("/getdata");
     }
   };
});
```

modify the controller like this

```
app.controller('DataCtrl', function($scope,$http,getData,$location,$routeParams){

   getData.getCity().then(function(response) {
      $scope.items = response.data;
      $scope.selectedItem = response.data[0];
   });

   $scope.change = function() {
      $location.path('/plumber-in/' + $scope.selectedItem.city);
   };
});
```

Comment: your answer is correct, don't know who down voted, further just remove `$scope` from `getData.getCity($scope).` and factory method  also. :)

Comment: I've upvoted your answer - because the downvote was misplaced by someone... This is a possible solution... Although the answer above (using `service`) would be personally more preferred by myself. :)

Comment: @sachila: just saw you answer. He wast to pass the "selected item from options" across different controllers. How does your answer solves this ?

Comment: @mechanicals  he is passing it through ` $location.path` as a parameter. so you don't need to create a separate factory function for that

Comment: 'When an option is selected I want to take this value to the next page'. 
I would think this question is more about how you can pass the data around controllers. Hence a generalised way wold be to have setter getter methods.

Comment: @sachila: I am not giving the information through as a parameter with $location.path. This only changes what comes after the url

Comment: @Larsmanson, in that case, create getter and setter like `mechanicals` mentioned. but avoid using scope inside the factory

Comment: @Larsmanson: pass in only the data you need as mentioned . rather than the whole scope. I'll update my code for that too.